# Как провести отсчет с момента какого -либо действия в Python, Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть фрагмент кода для того чтобы спавнить объект :

```
if len(AI_Bullets) < 100 :
  AI_Bullets.append(AI_shell(round(ai1[0] + 20 // 2) , round(ai1[1] + 20 // 2) , 5 , (0, 51, 102)))
```

но у него есть минус.Минус заключается в том, что объекты спавнятся постоянно.Можно ли сделать как-нибудь так, чтобы перед тем как выполнить append допустим пройдет 0,5 сек.?

Comment: А установить кол-во объектов? Попробуйте ограничить кол-во спавнившихся объектов.

Comment: Да можно, но это не совсем то, ибо если, допустим, ограничение 5, то пока эти 5 объектов не вылетят за опред. область, то новые не заспавнятся

Comment: С помощью  метода sleep библиотеки(стандартной) time можно приостановить работу на несколько указаных секунд. Почитайте в официальной док-ии: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep (Если не знаете английского google translate в помощь (И лучше начните паралельно изучать английский))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Импортируете библиотеку time и прописываете после нужного действия `time.sleep(время в секундах)`

Comment: Останавливает на указанное время программу в целом

Comment: Тогда поможет это: https://programmera.ru/uroki-po-python/metod-time-sleep-v-python/#Thread_Sleep